# Lim $1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}\ldots \frac{1}{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know that this is convergent. I've proven it with mathematical induction but I want to know what is the exact limit.I have no idea what to do. can anybody help me?             Lim  $1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}\ldots \frac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem

Comment: The answer: $$\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem

Comment: It isn't enough to speak of "the limit": you need to specify where $n$ is heading (in this case, "as $n$ is approaching infinity"). So instead of $\lim 1+\frac14+\cdots+\frac1{n^2}$, write $$\lim_{n\to\infty} 1+\frac14+\cdots+\frac1{n^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

See wikipedia for a myriad of solutions to the problem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem

You will see that they require specialized knowledge in some form or another.

Also, this paper which goes into detail about several different proofs:

https://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/cillerue/Curso/zeta2.pdf

But, because you'd like to know the limit

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} = \dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$$